# What is the relation between SIGCHLD and `waitpid()` or`wait()`?

Tags: linux, signals, system-calls, api, wait

If I am correct, a process waits for its children to terminate or stop by calling the `waitpid()` or `wait()` function.

What is the relation between SIGCHLD signal and the `waitpid()` or`wait()` functions?

- Is it correct   that when a process calls the `waitpid()` or `wait()` functions,
  the process  suspends itself until  a child process terminates/stops, which is the same as until a SIGCHLD signal is sent to it?

  (`pause()` suspends the current process until any signal is sent to it. So I wonder if `waitpid()` is similar, except that until SIGCHLD is sent to it?)
- When SIGCHLD is sent to a process which has been suspended by calling `waitpid()`, what is the order between executing SIGCHLD handler and resuming from suspension by `waitpid()`?
  (  In the following example from Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective, the SIGCHLD handler calls `waitpid()`.)

Thanks.

```c
void handler(int sig)
{
  int olderrno = errno;

  while (waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) > 0) {
    Sio_puts("Handler reaped child\n");
  }
  if (errno != ECHILD)
    Sio_error("waitpid error");
  Sleep(1);
  errno = olderrno;
}

int main()
{
  int i, n;
  char buf[MAXBUF];

  if (signal(SIGCHLD, handler1) == SIG_ERR)
    unix_error("signal error");

  /* Parent creates children */
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (Fork() == 0) {
      printf("Hello from child %d\n", (int)getpid());
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  /* Parent waits for terminal input and then processes it */
  if ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0)
    unix_error("read");

  printf("Parent processing input\n");
  while (1)
    ;

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Could you reword your question to make it a real question? What do you like to be answered?

Answer (score 7):

`wait()` is an outdated UNIX system call from the 1970s and `waitpid()` is an outdated UNIX system call from the 1980s.

In 1988, the superior interface `waitid()` has been introduced.

`signal()` is also an outdated interface from the 1970s. The recent interface is called `sigaction()` and allows to control the behavior of signals. A typical call in your case would be:

```
    struct sigaction sa; 

    sa.sa_sigaction = handler; 
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask); 
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO; 

    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL);
```

If you add `SA_NOCLDWAIT` to `sa.sa_flags`, you do not need to call `wait*()` at all and the system will not keep zombie processes until a `wait*()` call is made.

If you add `SA_NOCLDSTOP`, the SIGCHLD handler will not be called if a cild process exits.

If a `SIGCHLD`is generated, that would call a function:

```
void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *sip, void *context)
```

when a child process died. The parameter `sig` is filled with the signal number `SIGCHLD` and the second parameter is filled with the same information as you get from a call to `waitid()`, as in:

```
struct siginfo si;

ret = waitid(P_PID, pid, &si, WEXITED|WSTOPPED|WTRAPPED);
```

So if you are not interested in the status of the childs, it is possible to tell the system and if you are not interested in calling `wait*()`, but still like to get the process status, you can tell the system and use the information from the second parameter of the signal handler function.

When a child process died and `struct siginfo` is examined, the following fields are filled out:

```
si.si_signo   /* The signal number SIGCHLD */
si.si_code    /* The reason for the child to exit */
si.si_status  /* Either the parameter to exit(r) or signal number */
si.si_pid     /* The process id of the child that died */
```

If `si.si_code` contains the value `CLD_EXITED`, then `si.si_status` (on a POSIX system) contains the full 32 bits of the `exit()` code.

If `si.si_code` contains `CLD_KILLED`, `CLD_DUMPED`, `CLD_TRAPPED`, `CLD_STOPPED` or `CLD_CONTINUED`, then `si.si_status` contains the signal number that caused the status change.

Comment: Are you sure about `SA_NOCLDSTOP`? The man page mandates that this will ignore stop and continue signals, not termination.

Answer (score 4):

If installed, the signal handler is invoked by the kernel in the process when a child changes state (typically, exiting.) but it does not, by default, reap the child. A wait(2) or waitpid(2) call from inside or outside the handler is still needed for the child to be reaped. If SA_NOCLDWAIT is specified as an option to sigaction(2) when installing the SIGCHLD handler, then the kernel will automatically reap the child after the signal handler is delivered and no wait(2) call is needed to reap.

See the discussion of SA_NOCLDSTOP and SA_NOCLDWAIT options in the sigaction(2) man page as they relate to SIGCHLD.

Also, consider using sigaction(2) instead of signal(2) and allows you to use the three argument signal handler by specifying SA_SIGINFO. The siginfo_t structure reference will have additional, useful information as to why SIGCHLD is being delivered.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Are SIGCHLD signal and its handler used only in asychronous manner? (2) If a program installs a handler for SIGCHLD, and then calls fork() and waitpid() or wait(), what will happen when a child terminates? Does waitpid() or wait() return first and then the signal handler for SIGCHLD is invoked, or is the signal handler is invoked first and then waitpid() or wait() returns?

Comment: For (1), there is a block or non  blocking option for the waitpid call. As per here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094945/how-can-i-use-wait-as-a-non-blocking-command-in-unix

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough points to comment but this should answer your question.

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/waitpid.htm#:~:text=The%20waitpid()%20system%20call,options%20argument%2C%20as%20described%20below](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/waitpid.htm#:%7E:text=The%20waitpid()%20system%20call,options%20argument%2C%20as%20described%20below).

The signal raised will trigger the handler function you set for that specific signal type, which is SIGCHLD in your example.

Example here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792900/signal-and-sigchld-what-does-it-do

As you can see in the link just above, the wait() doesnt have to be inside the handler.

That just waits for the child process to terminate.

So basically, there is no direct relationship as such, just that a SIGCHLD signal will be
generated when a forked child process dies and that a wait() will wait till the child process terminates
properly.